# NodeJS post request doesn't return body

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm making a "GET" request to grap the session id from the URL then should send "POST" request with required form data which in result should return html body, but it doesn't. I'm not experienced in JS at all and tried to do something myself but can't figure out what's going wrong... I'm able to print out headers from POST request but body remains empty (and seems it hangs)

Also tried with `requests` module which throws `socket hang up` error.

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');

var conn_cookie;

var uri = "my_url.com";

var options_get = {
    host: uri,
    path: '/index.php',
    headers: {
        "User-Agent":  "Request"
    }
};

var postData = querystring.stringify({
    cert_num: "xxx",
    car_num: "yyy",
    answer: "0"
});

var options_post = {
    host: uri,
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/index.php',
    headers: {
        "User-Agent":  "Request",
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
    }
};

var post_req = http.request(options_post, function(res) {
    console.log("POST STATUS: " + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    // Nothing is happening here !!
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('Response: ' + chunk);
    });
});
post_req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

http.get(options_get, function(res) {
    conn_cookie = res.headers['set-cookie'];

    if (res.statusCode === 200) {
        //options_post['headers']['set-cookie'] = conn_cookie;
        console.log("SENDING POST DATA");

        post_req.write(postData);
        post_req.end();
    }
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Comment: there is one easy way to do this using [request](https://github.com/request/request)  npm module of nodejs

Comment: @IndraniSen hmmm i get `socket hang up` error... what can be the issue? headers?

Comment: add this `post_req.write('{"string": "Hello, World"}');
post_req.end();` post_req.end() will close will help to stop sock hangup error

Answer (score 1):

The post request is sending a body and you need to set the http request body size.

Add this to your post headers

```
 'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
```

Also, move your `var post_data` to before `var options_post`

*Buffer is global, so you don't need to require it*

Comment: Do you have to set the `path` to `/index.php` ?
Is your php script set up to respond to POST requests?

Comment: Yes i did try with that too... nothing is changing

Comment: It sounds like it might be your server. To debug, you can use this service  https://requestb.in/ then  set the post url to  the endpoint it gives you. Then you can rule out if the problem is your request, or the server.

Comment: unfortunately im doing web scraping so i dont have access to the main server

Comment: If your post request looks good in requestb.in then the problem lies on the remote server. It's not responding and not closing the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code , by create a sample server and trying to send a post request to server here my below code,its works for me,in your case  in GET call,you can test is post_req.end() is actually calling or not,

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');
var post_data = querystring.stringify({
 name: "Jack",
 surname: "Daniels",
 answer: "0"
 });

var options_post = {
  host: 'localhost',
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/test/data',
  port:9008,
  headers: {
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    accept: 'text/html',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    "User-Agent":  "Mozilla/5.0",
     'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(post_data)
  }
};

 var post_req = http.request(options_post, function(res) {
   console.log("POST STATUS: " + res.statusCode);
   console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
   res.setEncoding('utf8');

  // Nothing is happening here !!
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
     console.log('Response: ' + JSON.stringify(chunk));
    });
  });
   post_req.on('error', function(e) {
   console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
 });
 post_req.write(post_data);
 post_req.end();
```

Here my server code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express=require('express');
var app = express();
var port =  9008;


// Start the server

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // support encoded bodies

app.post("/test/data",function(req,res){

var body=req.body;
res.send("ok"+JSON.stringify(body));
});
//start the server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server has started!! ' + port);
```

And I got output:

```
HEADERS: {"x-powered-by":"Express","content-type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","content-length":"50","etag":"W/\"32-ml7xbrRwyj1GKXj
cJAYZOcmEm2s\"","date":"Mon, 26 Jun 2017 17:12:23 GMT","connection":"keep-alive"}
Response: "ok{\"name\":\"Jack\",\"surname\":\"Daniels\",\"answer\":\"0\"}"
```

[request](https://github.com/request/request) npm module is much easier doing POST/GET request one doesn't worry about much error handling and request closing and opening module handle everything.

Comment: doesn't work either... seems the server is completely fu**** up... interesting thing is that i can achieve my desired result over java or python

Comment: server `statusCode` returns `302` after performing post request, does it give you any clue whats going on?

Comment: I had tested its works for me , can you just test the above code just post request data ,  probably your code for GET call having issue,